# Select variable from JSON PHP POST data?

Tags: php, json, post

I have this post data from WebHook, I want to use it download a file using "fileUrl" variable (Marked with **). Problem that there's 3 "fileUrl" variables in JSON POST data that I get, how do I select the one I need?

```
Array
(
    [eventType] => OrderGenerated
    [data] => Array
        (
            [sellerID] => 32959
            [currencyCode] => EUR

            [orderDetails] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [detailOrderDetailCode] => 102
                            [detailQuantity] => 1
                            [detailPreviewUrl] => https://zakeke.blob.core.windows.net/files/images/design/previews/2020/10/26/9864c7500a6144b5b45005c29e515296.png
                            [detailFiles] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
Array
(
    [eventType] => OrderGenerated
    [data] => Array
        (
            [sellerID] => 32959
            [currencyCode] => EUR
            [orderDetails] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [detailOrderDetailCode] => 102

                            [detailModelCode] => 3061
                            [detailPreviewUrl] => https://zakeke.blob.core.windows.net/files/images/design/previews/2020/10/26/9864c7500a6144b5b45005c29e515296.png
                            [detailFiles] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [variantName] => Sample color
                                            [format] => pdf
                                            **[fileUrl]** => https://zakeke.blob.core.windows.net/files/images/design/2020/10/26/s-32959/571431/out/fd68c734ec2b488bb0f0db3f452dc896/161978_1_40088_1.pdf
                                        )
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [variantName] => Sample color
                                            [format] => dxf
                                            [fileUrl] => https://zakeke.blob.core.windows.net/files/images/design/2020/10/26/s-32959/571431/out/5b67739598374a9294c2db2ffae9803f/161978_1_40088_1.dxf
                                        )
                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [variantName] => Sample color
                                            [format] => dxf
                                            [fileUrl] => https://zakeke.blob.core.windows.net/files/images/design/2020/10/26/s-32959/571431/out/a5f20867fe3c4318b0bd70b3957ce8a9/161978_1_40088_1_HQ.dxf
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Anyways, I got this little thing written:

```
<?php
$webhookResponse = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

//Retrieve the url from the data object, via the id property
$messageId = $webhookResponse["data"]["orderDetails"]["detailFiles"]["fileUrl"];

$file = 'testas.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $messageId, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

but I have no idea how to tell $messageId where to look file for, what's the correct sytanx here. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot ignore the arrays - `$webhookResponse["data"]["orderDetails"][0]["detailFiles"][0]["fileUrl"];` So looks like you will need to write a couple of loops to get all the URLS

Comment: Thank you, worked just as I wanted it too. I feel stupid for how simple this looks, but oh well. Thanks again!